# Automation script element Identified first time but dont verified second time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
  public void iclickontemplatetab(){
            SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"global_nav_sidebar\"]/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
         }
        public void iclickonanalyticstab(){
            SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"global_nav_sidebar\"]/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[6]/a")).click();
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the stacktrace? What is the HTML for the page you are interacting with. Please edit your question to add this information. See [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait (Implicit or explicit) if you are doing some actions before revisiting the elements for second time

Comment: Thanks for this valuable answer really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void iclickontemplatetab(){
        SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("....")).click();
     }
```

Avoid using copy paste Xpaths. Instead use manual xpaths. Like: //tagname[@attribute=’Value‘]

Comment: what sort of help we get from manual xpaths if you please explain it would be great for me and other people around us.

Comment: @farooqnaeem Since the absolute xpath are the XPath that starts from Root node with following a hierarchy to the element with corresponding nodes from the page. nodes path represent like ‘/’. So,The major disadvantage in Absolute XPath Expressions is that they change for simple UI changes on the Web Pages. Like when there is even a sligh change in position the the xpath won't work.